# Ejercicio, girar contenido de la matriz

Tags: c++, matrices

hola comunidad necesito su ayuda con este ejercicio de C++, la importante es solo usar ciclos básicos como while if, for...(no funciones)...esto es lo que tengo solo la  opción 1 , sólo necesito si pueden a corregirlo o darme algunos consejos.
La opción 2 no la puse porque tengo lo mismo pero con los parámetros invertido, sabiendo como solucionar la opción 1 yo hago la opción 2.
LES DEJO UNA IMAGEN DE REFERENCIA. 
Para entenderlo, al presionar opción 1 este debe hacer un giro de los bordes (filas y columnas) 1 bloque en sentido horario.
ojala puedan ayudarme...se los agradezco!

[image: ejercicio_propuesto]

```
main(){
char M[5][5];
int i, j, aux, opcion;

//crear natriz
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    for(j=0; j<5; j++){
    M[i][j]={' '};
    }
}


M[0][0]='a';    M[2][4]='g';
M[0][1]='b';    M[3][0]='n';
M[0][2]='c';    M[3][4]='h';
M[0][3]='d';    M[4][0]='m';
M[0][4]='e';    M[4][1]='l';
M[1][0]='p';    M[4][2]='k';
M[1][4]='f';    M[4][3]='j';
M[2][0]='o';    M[4][4]='i';


//Imprimir matriz inicial
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    for(j=0; j<5; j++){
    printf ("%2c|",M[i][j]);
    }
cout<<endl;
}

//opciones de giro
opcion=1;

while(opcion!=9){
cout<<"Digite una opcion: 1=giro Derecha, 2=giro Izquierda y para 9=Salir: ";
cin>>opcion;


      if(opcion==1){
            aux=M[4][4];     

            if(i==0){ 

                for (i<5; i=0; i++){
                    for(j<5; j=1; j--){
                    M[0][j]=M[0][j-1];

                    }
                }
            }


            if(j==0){ //columna 0
                for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                    for(j=0; j<5; j++){
                    M[i][0]=M[i+1][0];  
                    }   
                }

            }

            if(i==4){ //fila 4
                for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                    for(j=0; j<5; j++){
                    M[4][j]=M[4][j+1];
                    }   
                }   
            }

            if(j==4){ //columna 4
                for(i<5; i=0; i--){
                    for(j<5; j=0; j--){
                    M[i][4]=M[i-1][4];  
                    }   
                }
            }
            M[3][4]=aux;

    }//fin opcion 1


    if(opcion<1 || opcion>3){ //vuelve a preguntar
    cout<<"Digite una opcion, 1=giro Derecha, 2=giro Izquierda, 9=Salir :";
    cin>>opcion;    
    }

    if (opcion==9) //termina
    opcion=9;

    //Imprimir matriz
    system("cls");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        for(j=0; j<5; j++){
        printf ("%2c|",M[i][j]);
        }
    cout<<endl;
    }

    }//fin while

cout<<"***FIN PROGRAMA***";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola! Disculpa, no entiendo cuál es tu pregunta. ¿Qué problema tienes con el código que nos compartes?

Comment: hola estimado gracias por comentar,no me realiza el cambio de las variables o la impresión de la nueva matriz actualizada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me pareció interesante tu pregunta y decidí darle un intento y, hay que explicar algunas cosas:

Este ejercicio tiene cierta complejidad que termina siendo ilegible sin funciones, es fácil de realizar, sin embargo, no es buena práctica meter todo dentro de `main` para resolver el problema, así que voy a explicar todo el contenido y al final dejaré un link con todo el código dentro de `main` para el propósito de tu ejercicio.

Iniciemos :)

En el ejercicio, necesitamos "rotar" de manera circular una matriz, el enfoque que he tomado hace uso de 2 matrices, una donde guardas los valores y otra donde operas para realizar los cambios necesarios, así que esto nos deja con una función para ajustar los valores en la matriz "final":

```
void array_set(char dst[MAX_LEN][MAX_LEN], char src[MAX_LEN][MAX_LEN]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_LEN; j++) 
      dst[i][j] = src[i][j];
}
```

Posterior a ello, he implementado la función para rotar hacia la izquierda:

```
// Mueve el contenido de forma circular hacia la derecha en el array multidimensional.
void rotate_left(char a[MAX_LEN][MAX_LEN]) {
  char newArr[MAX_LEN][MAX_LEN] = {0}; // Array de destino.

  // Primero rotamos los valores de la primera fila hacia la izquierda.
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN - 1; i++) 
    newArr[0][i] = a[0][i + 1];

  // Movemos hacia arriba todos los valores de la ultima columna.
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN - 1; i++) 
    newArr[i][MAX_LEN - 1] = a[i + 1][MAX_LEN - 1];

  // Movemos hacia la derecha todos los valores de la ultima fila.
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN - 1; i++)
    newArr[MAX_LEN - 1][i + 1] = a[MAX_LEN - 1][i];

  // Por ultimo, movemos la primera columna hacia abajo.
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN - 1; i++) 
    newArr[i + 1][0] = a[i][0];

  array_set(a, newArr);
}
```

Lo que hace esta función es mover los valores de una matríz a otra mientras se cambian los indices de destino, los comentarios en la función indican lo que hace cada bucle `for`.

Para la función que rota el contenido hacia la derecha, es esencialmente lo contrario:

```
// Mueve el contenido de forma circular hacia la izquierda en el array multidimensional.
void rotate_right(char a[MAX_LEN][MAX_LEN]) {
  char newArr[MAX_LEN][MAX_LEN] = {0};

  // Movemos todos los valores de la primera fila hacia la derecha.
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN - 1; i++) 
    newArr[0][i + 1] = a[0][i];

  // Movemos los valores de la última columna hacia abajo.
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN - 1; i++) 
    newArr[i + 1][MAX_LEN - 1] = a[i][MAX_LEN - 1];

  // Movemos hacia la izquierda los valores de la última fila.
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN - 1; i++)
    newArr[MAX_LEN - 1][i] = a[MAX_LEN - 1][i + 1];

  // Por ultimo, movemos la primera columna hacia arriba.
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN - 1; i++) 
    newArr[i][0] = a[i + 1][0];

  array_set(a, newArr);
}
```

Ahora necesitamos una función que se encargue de imprimir la matríz antes de seleccionar:

```
// Imprime el contenido del array.
void print_array(char arr[MAX_LEN][MAX_LEN]) {
  std::cout << '\n';
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LEN; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_LEN; j++)
      std::cout << '\t' << arr[i][j] << (((j + 1) == MAX_LEN)? '\n': ' ');
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Con esto ya tenemos la implementación completa del algoritmo especificado en el ejercicio, estas dos funciones son capaces de rotar el contenido de manera circular en ambas matrices, solo tenemos que enlazar todo en la misma pieza:

```
// Punto de inicio.
int main() {
  // El array que vamos a operar.
  char arr[MAX_LEN][MAX_LEN] = {
    { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' },
    { 'p', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'f' },
    { 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'g' },
    { 'n', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'h' },
    { 'm', 'l', 'k', 'j', 'i' },
  };

  while (1) {
    print_array(arr);
    std::cout << "Opciones: \n"
              << "\t1. Girar izquierda\n\t2. Girar derecha.\n\t9. Salir.\n\n"
              << "Elegir: "; 

    int opt = 0;     // Opción a ejecutar.
    std::cin >> opt; // No hay check de los datos.
    switch (opt) {
      case 1: rotate_left(arr); break;
      case 2: rotate_right(arr); break;
      case 9: return 0;
      default: std::cout << "Opcion invalida.\n"; break;
    }
  }
}
```

Este algoritmo puede ser optimizado para mayor rendimiento, así que trata de mejorarlo lo más que puedas :)

Enlaces:

- Aquí te dejo un [repl.it](https://repl.it/@IamNaCl/EjercicioMatriz) con la solución funcionando, es la solución que escribí en esta respuesta.
- [Este otro repl.it](https://repl.it/@IamNaCl/EjercicioMatrizSinManosMama) es la solución sin funciones que solicita tu ejercicio.

En los enlaces arriba hay una macro llamada `MAX_LEN`, se usa para especificar la longitud de las matrices (cuadradas) sobre las que vas a operar, si por alguna razón no funciona el código, agrega: `#define MAX_LEN (5)` al inicio del archivo y seguro que funciona.

Saludos!

Comment: te las mandaste!!! agradecido..lo que deduje es que lo mas importante es usar 2 matrices no  1 como lo estaba haciendo  ademas de otras cosa...MUY AGRADECIDO!

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS POR TU TIEMPO!!, voy a analizarlo y te comento, ya que aun hay cosas que no las entiendo pero me toca ami buscar eso .

Comment: Lo que no entiendas puedes preguntarlo aquí y yo edito mi respuesta :)

Answer (score 1):

Para rotar los elementos periféricos de la matriz yo creo que es mucho más sencillo utilizar un vector secundario:

```
char* exterior[] = { &M[0][0], &M[0][1], &M[0][2], &M[0][3],
                     &M[0][4], &M[1][4], &M[2][4], &M[3][4],
                     &M[4][4], &M[4][3], &M[4][2], &M[4][1],
                     &M[4][0], &M[3][0], &M[2][0], &M[1][0] };
```

De esta forma podemos realizar las rotaciones tratando dichos elementos de una forma lineal. Nota que hemos declarado un vector de punteros, de tal forma que podemos modificar directamente los valores de la matriz `M`.

Así, para realizar una rotación antihoraria nos bastaría con un bucle tal que:

```
     char temp = *exterior[0];
     for(int i=0; i<15; i++)
     {
       *exterior[i] = *exterior[i+1];
     }
     *exterior[15] = temp;
```

Mientras que para hacer una rotación en sentido horario:

```
     char temp = *exterior[15];
     for(int i=15; i>0; i--)
     {
       *exterior[i] = *exterior[i-1];
     }
     *exterior[0] = temp;
```

Comment: amigo es posible enviar el código completo con las librerías que usas??  se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: El código completo es el que ves... crea la matriz y pon uno de los dos algoritmos que ves... cada vez que llames a uno de ellos el anillo exterior de la matriz rotará en un sentido o en otro

Comment: aa ok  entiendo, gracias.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(opcion == 1) {

  for(i=0; i<5; i++){

    for(j=0; j<5; i++){ 

      if(M[i][j] != ' '){

        if(M[i][j] == 'A'){
          M[i][j] == 'P';
        }

        else {
          M[i][j]--;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Qué tiene de especial el 65? Trata de que tus recomendaciones sean claras para cualquiera que lea tu respuesta ahora y en el futuro. :) Y, si quieres mostrar cómo hacer lo que dices usando código, tanto mejor

Comment: Considera por favor dejar la explicación, pues eso mas el código mejoran mucho tu aporte, te recomiendo leer [answer]

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución Davis, es importante revisar [answer] y editar tu respuesta,saludos!